# Trying to get the last message from each conversation in the same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table name message and I am trying to get the last message from each conversation which is store in the same table. I tried looking similar question over StackOverflow but seem like no luck. This question is not duplicate since I have to get the last message from by_uid=>to_uid OR to_uid <= by_uid

This is my table message

```
id  by_uid  to_uid  msg
1   3         4     hi
2   3         4     hello
3   4         3     where
4   3         5     hey there
5   3         6     that's ok
6   6         3     really?
7   4         2     hiiiiii
```

What I am expecting is

```
id  by_ui   to_uid    msg
3   4         3       where
4   3         5       hey there
6   6         3       really?
7   4         2       hiiiiii
```

I am trying to achieve the above output with the below query.

```
SELECT  message.*
        FROM message join (select max(id) maxid, to_uid from message group by to_uid) latest
        on message.id=latest.maxid and message.to_uid=latest.to_uid
        WHERE message.to_uid = 3 OR message.by_uid = 3
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I have updated my question. Please have a look